# Error: (data: string) => number' is not assignable to type '() => void'

Tags: typescript, onclick, shopify

Running into an error when trying to push string to array.
All help is appreciated.

Error message @ onClick:

> Type '(productName: string) => number' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
> types.d.ts(59, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'

I've include the associated code below

```
const productList : string[] = [];
const handleClick = useCallback((productName:string) => productList.push(productName),[]);
```

JSX

```
<Button primary onClick={handleClick}>Add Product</Button>
```

Comment: What string are you expecting to get from onClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the button know what product you clicked?

The answer is that you need make a new function for each button to pass in the product that was clicked.

For example:

```
function Button({ onClick, children }: { onClick: () => void, children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
}

function ProductList() {
  const productList : string[] = []; // this should be state
  const handleClick = useCallback((productName:string) => productList.push(productName),[]);
  
  return <>
    <div>
      Product A
      <Button onClick={() => handleClick('A')}>Add Product</Button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Product B
      <Button onClick={() => handleClick('B')}>Add Product</Button>
    </div>
  </>
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

---

Final note that `productList` [should be state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and not a simple variable. If you just push things into array, react will never notice, and never re-render anything. That's a different problem entirely, but figured I should mention it.